# jQuery and php accordion menu doing weird thing

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

[image]So I've got this little accordion menu I made using jQuery and php.

It works well apart from the fact that when I click hide all items it opens everything then closes it, when show all is clicked it hides everything then shows it.

I want if i press hide all to hide it straight away without showing everything first and the other way around when show all is clicked.

I'm using count() to count the items in the menu then incrementing it by one when the function ends.

Anyway, here's the code:

jQuery:

```
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                      $ = jQuery;
                      $( document ).ready(function () {
                          $( "#heading_<?php echo $count; ?>, .personal-lessons-show-all, .personal-lessons-hide-all" ).on("click", function () {
                            $( "#lessons_<?php echo $count; ?>" ).slideToggle().css( "display", "block" );
                            $( "body" ).css( "background-color", "#eee" );
                            $( ".right-purple-background" ).css( "height", "1124px" );
                          }); 
                          $( ".personal-lessons-show-all" ).on( "click", function () {
                            $( "#lessons_<?php echo $count; ?>" ).slideDown();
                            $( ".personal-lessons-hide-all" ).show();
                            $( "body" ).css( "background-color", "#eee" );
                            $( ".right-purple-background" ).css( "height", "1124px" );
                          });
                          $( ".personal-lessons-hide-all" ).on( "click", function () {
                            $( "#lessons_<?php echo $count; ?>" ).slideUp();
                            $( ".personal-lessons-hide-all" ).hide();
                            $( "body" ).css( "background-color", "white" );
                            $( ".right-purple-background" ).css( "height", "1200px" );
                          });
                          $( ".bordered-title" ).on( "hover", function () {
                            $( this ).css( "cursor", "pointer" );
                          });
                      });
                    </script>
```

And the php:

```
             <?php
                // Loop through all of the lesson categories
              $count = 0;
                foreach($lessons as $key => $val){
              $count++;   
                  // Get personal lessons for logged in user
                  $personal_lessons = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'personal-lessons', true);

                  $yes_to_all = false;
                  if(empty($personal_lessons[$_GET['course']]) || !$personal_lessons[$_GET['course']]){
                    $yes_to_all = true;
                  }

                  $category_name = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT name FROM mdl_course_categories WHERE id = '$key'");
                  ?>
                    <p class="bordered-title" id="heading_<?php echo $count; ?>"><?php echo $category_name->name; ?></p>
                      <div class="table-responsive">
                      <table id="lessons_<?php echo $count; ?>" class="lessonsTable table-responsive"> 

                        <?php
```

Comment: `$(this)` is your best friend...

Comment: Could you re-create a code snippet or a jsfiddle that reproduces your issue? Your code is a bit heavy

Comment: I'll try incorporating this but I don't really see how it can change much. As you may have noticed, I referencing multiple objects in one code block so using (this) maybe isn't the best thing?

Comment: I'll try reproducing it but It has php to, that's how it counts the elements. Can i write some basic php in jsfiddle? I haven't used it much.

Comment: Well, from what I can see, your PHP is not needed here. The problem is with your JS

Comment: Hi @Stefan Vujic as you topic said is a problem of rendering so if you want to do a demo : i guess copy paste the HTML and no the source PHP.

Comment: You don't need to write the PHP, just hard code the basic HTML structure with lorem ipsum as filler and apply your JS transitions to it.

Comment: Ok, this may take a while, I'll get back to you. Thanks

Comment: @Stefan Vujic Welcome and thanks for you too

Comment: Also has hide and show buttons' class ".personal-lessons-show-all, .personal-lessons-hide-all" in first function, and is mean problem when U click hide or show.

Comment: @La Fortuna Thanks, you were right, those buttons were the problem, it was pretty clear, I don't know how i didn't see , anyway, thank you very much ;)